How to Perform a Multipart/Form-Data POST Request for Login using curl-cffi in Python?
I'm able to login to a website by sending a POST request with multipart/form-data using requests. The login process requires a CSRF token, which I have to extract from the login page first. However, I am trying to do the same attempt with no luck using curl-cffi.
Here’s a simplified version of what I have so far using requests:
import requests
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class CSRFTokenScraper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.csrf_token = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == 'input':
            attrs_dict = dict(attrs)
            if attrs_dict.get('name') == 'csrf_token':
                self.csrf_token.append(attrs_dict.get('value'))

class Session:
    def __init__(self, login_url, username, password, timeout=10):
        self.login_url = login_url
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.timeout = timeout
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session.verify = False
        self.csrf_token_scraper = CSRFTokenScraper()

    def login(self):
        # Step 1: Get the login page to extract CSRF token
        token_response = self.session.get(self.login_url, timeout=self.timeout)
        self.csrf_token_scraper.feed(token_response.text)
        csrf_token = self.csrf_token_scraper.csrf_token[0]

        # Step 2: Prepare the multipart/form-data payload
        files = {
            'csrf_token': (None, csrf_token),
            'username': (None, self.username),
            'password': (None, self.password),
        }

        # Step 3: Send the POST request
        headers = {
            'Referer': self.login_url,
        }
        response = self.session.post(self.login_url, files=files, headers=headers, timeout=self.timeout)
        return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    URL = "URL"
    USER = "USER"
    PWD = "PWD"

    session = Session(login_url=URL, username=USER, password=PWD)
    login_response = session.login()
    print(f"Status Code: {login_response.status_code}")

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Can you describe the actual and expected behavior of the snippet?
